# How to re-route people abusing URLs in .htaccess or with PHP?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I currently have an app that looks similar to this.

www.domain.com -> Homepage
www.domain.com/brand -> Route to proper brand page

However, someone is abusing my app by requesting www.domain.com/brand/extra/

Can I make a rule in .htaccess to route anyone typing in extra URL paths to somewhere or in my PHP app, block against this?  I am not using any framework and someone is attacking my server resources by abusing this.

```
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url_parsed = parse_url( $url );
$parts  = explode( '/', $url_parsed['path'] );
$output = implode( '/', array_slice( $parts, 0, 2 ) );
$player_id = trim( $output, '/' );
$qa_check = isset( $_GET['qa'] ) ? $_GET['qa'] : false;
```

Here is the .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

The above code allows me to trim away everything and just use the first text after the first / but it still routes a person to the URL they asked for and is causing major issues.

How can I better handle this routing?

Comment: How would you want to determine what is “extra”? I am assuming you don’t only have URLs with just one single folder in the path accross your whole application? Then you will have to do this at the point where you determine what the real URL for the specific requested content was _supposed_ to be.

Comment: The application actually has no subfolders.  It just has a main index.php file that all traffic routes to.  When someone types in /path it takes the path and looks in the database for what content to serve for the path.  That's why I don't have a need for anything over one slash in the path.  I believe my only option though is just to trim off all the extra and put in better error checking to not cause so much resource usage.

Comment: Something like `RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.+$ somewhereelse` should probably do. Match something out of the character class that does not contain the slash, then a slash, then something else after that.